# Ошибка "1004" при запуске макроса

Tags: vba

Подскажите, пожалуйста, после запуска макроса появляется окно с надписью: "Нельзя установить свойство Locked класса Range". И показывает ошибку в макросе: Target.Locked = True
Что необходимо изменить/предпринять?

Comment: Необходимо показать пример. Одна из возможных причин: пытаетесь изменить свойство диапазона на защищенном листе.